# How to save csv file with custom delimiter in MS Excel,without change system setting?

Tags: excel, csv

I have an issue that whenever I save my MS Excel-2016 file the delimiter that I use in this is "$",but after saving it converts to default ",".

Without changing the system setting ,going to control panel,selecting Region & country,I want to solve this issue.

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that without changing your system settings, as that isn't a save option. A list of the options can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-a-workbook-to-text-format-txt-or-csv-3e9a9d6c-70da-4255-aa28-fcacf1f081e6.

Just stating the obvious: if your data doesn't contain any commas you can just open the file in notepad and then find and replace (ctrl + h) the commas with the $.